# error de google auth 2.0 con symfony

Tags: php, symfony, plesk

Estoy intentando crear una web con Symfony usando plesk (es mi primera vez jaja). Estoy haiendo el login a través de google, pero cuando se supone que la API te tiene que redirigir al controlador (la URl a la que quiero redirigir funciona si la escribo manualmente) que yo le indico en redirectUri en el config.php (ya he añadido la URL en la consola de google), pero me da un error de que no tengo permisos para acceder a ese documento.
Aquí dejo el código de mi index.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../google-login/config.php';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

  $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
  $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
  $email =  $google_account_info->email;
  $name =  $google_account_info->name;

  echo $email .'<br>';
  echo $name ;
  
} else {

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId($clientID);
  $client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
  $client->addScope("email");
  $client->addScope("profile");
  
  echo "<a href='".$client->createAuthUrl()."'>Google Login</a>";
}
```

Mi intención es que una vez te logeas con la API de google, te redirija a una URL y ahí ya hagas lo que necesite.